# What is wrong with this example in TCL book

Tags: tcl

I am reading "Tcl/Tk: A developer's guide", in chapter 3.1, it has such bad example:

```
if {$x > 2} {
     set greater true
}
```

The book says this code is wrong syntax because "`No space between test and body left brace`" and will get error message:

```
Error Message: invalid command name "}"
```

I tried it in tclsh, it works fine. Also I do not think "`{$x`" is wrong, "{" is at the start position of a word, so whatever stuff till the matching "}" is enclosed.

Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: my guess is that you didn't copy the code from the book correct. Doesn't it say: if {$x > 2}{set greater true} i.e.:  a }{ without a space in between? Please check that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book, it is given without spaces only.

[image]

Running this we will the get the following errors.

```
% if {$x > 2}{
extra characters after close-brace
%      set greater true
true
% }
invalid command name "}"
%
```